# Declaring Hooks with let

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new To React Hooks. I was wondering can we just declare hooks using  "let" instead of "const". In the Code both works. The problem with const is we cannot re-assigned the value. But if the hook is declare with let then we can. So is it a good way to declare the hooks with let rather than const?

const [counter,increaseCounter] = useState(1);

let [counter,increaseCounter] =useState(1);

Comment: Why are you wanting to re-assign the value of a hook? I can't think of a case where this would be needed or a good idea. Using const is preferred here.

Comment: What would be the point? Reassigning a hook would be nonsensical.

Comment: You should be using react hook's effects if you wish to update the value.

Answer (score 0):

--> "The problem with const is we cannot re-assigned the value."

I think we can still re-assigned a value with it, because what react do is it creates a new ref for that state when it is changed.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to reassign values to the named constants, they're constant.

Comment: You're right, my bad - what I mean is he can change the value of a hook declared with const :) sorry for my english.